# htaccess removing index.php only root folder

Tags: .htaccess, web, root

Matured one question which I can not handle himself and is forced to ask for help.
So...

I have configured .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index\.php($|\ |\?)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]
```

This code removes all directories index.php on site. I also need to remove it only in the site root. The problem is that the root can be any subdirectory as "/" and "/some_folder/" 
Is it possible to do this without explicit basedir?

For example for CNC I managed to make it so:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . ./ [L]
```

**Thus, the problem:** 
Site root = httр://site.com/sub/
Remove index.php need only in the root directory. 
Rot directory may vary and the decision should be without explicit basedir

Comment: It is unclear to me what you want to do.  In other words, what exactly should the input be and what should the output be?

Comment: site root = httр://site.com/sub_dir/; input = /site.com/sub_dir/index.php; output = /site.com/sub_dir/; input2 = /site.com/sub_dir/sub2/index.php; output2 = /site.com/sub_dir/sub2/index.php;

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule to remove index.php from root only:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: unfortunately it does not work if the directory is a subfolder

Comment: But you want to remove index.php only if it is root or did I misunderstand it?

Comment: Yes, but in my case the root is the place where it is lying htaccess, and the site and may have htaccess and subdirectories, then shift to a subfolder of the root.

Comment: You mean this .htaccess is placed in a sub-directory? root is always `domain.com/index.php` not `domain.com/sub/index.php` can you clarify what exactly do you want from this rule?

Comment: .htaccess placed in the same directory, which is considered the start point of the run site (where placed main index.php) That's just in this directory and must retire from index.php

Comment: Still unclear what you want. If URL is `domain.com/sub/index.php` then what it should become?